# Cycle through the open windows on a Desktop

Tags: finder

I'd like to switch open windows on a particular desktop without jumping to any other desktop. If App1 has 1 open window and App2 has 2 open windows then I expect focus to visit the all of them as I cycle through. This behavior is essentially the same as i3s mod+↑ behavior.

Comment: The question might be easier to understand if you don't assume that people here know about i3s :-)

Comment: I think without 3rd party help, best you can do is Ctrl/F4, which rather arbitrarily jumps around windows in a single Space… but will get stuck if any window has a search bar.